# Having trouble getting the observer pattern working

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have been trying to no avail to get the observer pattern working in a relatively simple application.

I have 4 GUI classes

- **StarterClass** (contains a `CompositeWordLists` and a `CompositeWordListData`)
- **CompositeWordLists** (contains many `CompositeListItem`/s and a `CompositeWordListData`)

  - **CompositeListItem**
- **CompositeWordListData** (Contains a `DialogWordData`)

  - **DialogWordData**

Here is my Observable

```
interface Observable<T> {
    void addObserver(T o);
    void removeObserver(T o);
    void removeAllObservers();
    void notifyObservers();
}
```

And I am creating Observers like this:

```
public class Observers {
    private Observers(){};

    interface WordListsObserver {
        public void update(CompositeWordLists o);
    }   

    interface ListItemObserver {
        public void update(CompositeListItem o);
    }
}
```

Basically I am having trouble with specifying the sort of event that occurred.  For example, the `CompositeWordLists` class needs to know when a `CompositeListItem` is deleted, saved edited etc but I only have one update method ... my brain hurts now!

What is a better way of doing this?

---

### UPDATE

Still having trouble with this, I added events and changed Observable and Observers but now I have type safety problems.

```
public class Observers {
    private Observers(){};

    /**
     * @param <T> the object that is passed from the Observable
     */
    interface ObservableEvent<T> {
        T getEventObject();
    }


    /**
     * Get notified about Authentication Attempts
     */
    interface ObserverAuthenticationAttempt {
        /**
         * @param e true if authentication was successful
         */
        public void update(ObservableEvent<Boolean> e); 
    }


    /**
     * Get notified about a Word Deletion
     */
    interface ObserverWordDeleted {
        /**
         * @param e the id of the word that was deleted
         */
        public void update(ObservableEvent<Integer> e); 
    }
}
```

The Observable Interface now looks like this

```
interface Observable<T> {
    void addObserver(T o);
    void removeObserver(T o);
    void removeAllObservers();
    <K> void  notifyObservers(Observers.ObservableEvent<K> e);
}
```

The problem is that when I implement this I get and would have to cast K to the appropriate type, not really what I want to do.

```
@Override
public <K> void notifyObservers(ObservableEvent<K> e) {
    for(Observers.ObserverAuthenticationAttempt o : this.observers)
        o.update(e);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

### update 2

Actually it works better with an Observable like this, but I still need to specify the correct EventType in two different places.

```
interface Observable<T,K> {
    void addObserver(T o);
    void removeObserver(T o);
    void removeAllObservers();
    void  notifyObservers(Observers.ObservableEvent<K> e);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to parametrise the Observers, but you need to parametrize the events.

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    void notify(T event);
}
```

An example event:

```
public class WordListUpateEvent {

    private final int changedIndex;

    public WordListUpateEvent(int changedIndex) {       
        this.changedIndex = changedIndex;
    }

    public int getChangedIndex() {
        return changedIndex;
    }
}
```

Then you can have different interface of it for example:

```
public interface WordListObserver extends Observer<WordListUpateEvent> {}
```

and its implementations

```
public class ConcreteWordListObserverA implements WordListObserver {
    @Override
    public void notify(WordListUpateEvent event) {
        System.out.println("update item at index: " + event.getChangedIndex());
    }
}
```

on the other hand you need your Observable interface, i have splitted it in two interface in order ti make the notifyObservers method not public to the observers (you will see it later):

```
public interface Observable<T> extends ObservableRegistration<T> {  
    void notifyObservers(T event);
}

public interface ObservableRegistration<T> {

    void addObserver(Observer<T> o);
    void removeObserver(Observer<T> o);
    void removeAllObservers();
}
```

If you would have several observables in a subject, you can not implemnt the Observalbe interface direct to your subject, so you need a seperate implementation class:

```
public class ObservableImpl<T> implements Observable<T>{

    private final List<Observer<T>> observers = new ArrayList<Observer<T>>();

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer<T> o) {
        this.observers.add(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Observer<T> o) {
        this.observers.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAllObservers() {
        this.observers.clear();     
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(T event) {      
        for(Observer<T> observer : observers) {
            observer.notify(event);
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can use the implementation in your subject:

```
public class Subject {

    private Observable<WordListUpateEvent> wordListObservable = new ObservableImpl<WordListUpateEvent>(); 

    //private Subject<OtherEvent> otherObservable = new ObservableImpl<WordListUpateEvent>();


    public ObservableRegistration<WordListUpateEvent> getWordListObservableRegistration() {
        return this.wordListObservable;
    }

//  public ObservableRegistration<OtherEvent> getOtherRegistration() {
//      return this.otherObservable;
//  }

    public void doSomething() {
        this.wordListObservable.notifyObservers(new WordListUpateEvent(42));
    }

}
```

And this is how you can connect the observer and the subject:

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subject subject = new Subject();

        subject.getWordListObservableRegistration().addObserver(new ConcreteWordListObserverA());
        subject.getWordListObservableRegistration().addObserver(new ConcreteWordListObserverA());

        subject.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Ralph, I will have a good look at this and see how I go

Comment: IMHO `subject.getWordListObservableRegistration()` is really not required here; you can handle the additional logic required for observer registration internally. `subject.addObserver()` should be good enough by making the Subject class implement the Observable interface. That also passes logical tests like `subject instanceof Observable`. Of course, YMMV :)

Comment: @Sanjay: You are right, if there is only one Observable (Interface) for the subject -- But if there are two or more (one for word list, and one for other), then you will get in trouble if you not want to implement the observer implementation stuff by hand.  -- Of course you can implement delegate methods in Subject, but I believe the idea behind jax's Observable Interface is to write as less code as possible.

Comment: I fully agree with your reasoning; it's just that the question posed by the OP had no such requirement hence I came up with the simplest solution possible in the given scenario. :-)

Comment: it worked.  I disagree with @Sanjay, a complete understanding is a good thing, besides, you started with the simplest scenario and expanded it stating your reasons, I appreciate the extra info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Observer interface, containing a `public void update(ObservableEvent oe)` method, and an ObserverEvent interface. After that, you can create specific class for each of your events.

Comment: Create? Why not just use `java.util.Observer`?

Comment: @Traroth I tried what you said but still cant get it working with generics properly, see my updated question

Comment: @musiKk because you have to `extend` java.util.Observable and there is no type safety

Comment: @musiKk : jax asked how to implement the Observer pattern, not where he can find an existing implementation. I, for one, try to answer the question actually asked...

Comment: @jax : can you describe the problems you get?

Comment: @Traroth The problem is that when I call `o.update(e);` the update method does not know what the type is because of the `<K>` type. I would have to cast it to the appropriate type which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/Observableandobserver.htm

The Java Observer's update method has the Object argument. You can pass any Object, thus you can create your own "UpdateMessage" Object that can contain the updated object and additional information about what happend (deleted, saved etc.).

Comment: This doesn't help with regards to the OP's own Observer implementation.