# Double observer in java?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have a problem with Observer pattern.

First, I have a HttpHelper class to get data from server, I used it as Observerable.

```
 public class HttpHelper extends Observable,Runnable{
    public void run(){
      //do long task to get data
      String result = getData();
      setChanged();
      notifyObservers(result);
   }
 }
```

The DataManager class get data from HttpHerlper when completed, then do some business task.

```
public class DataManager implements Observer {
    public void doTask(){
    HttpHelper helper = new HttpHelper();
    helper.addObserver(this); 
    Thread thread = new Thread(helper);
    thread.start();
    }
    public void update(Observable obj, Object data) {
       if (data instanceof String) {
         // do some stuff with this data
         // Then I want to notify the result to the view
         Model model = doSomething(data);
         notify(model)
       }
    }
}
```

Finaaly, View class will update data when DataManager complete task.

```
  public class View{
       private void getData(){
           DataManager manager = new DataManager()
           manager.doTask();
       }
       public void update(Observable obj, Object data) {

       }
 }
```

Should I use Observer again? And how can I do that?
P/s: for some reason, HttpHelper and DataManager must be separated.

**Update**: Here is the class structure
https://www.dropbox.com/s/givn6vzvqr4cgye/bkd.png

Comment: What is the purpose of the View Class? Presentation?

Comment: Yes, it will display the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the relationship between HttpHelper and DataManager doesn't need an observer pattern. It seems to be just a callback to notify the manager that the processing is done. Observers are better suited for dispatching events to multiple, different listeners via a common interface, not to a single listener. Having said that, what you have will work. Check [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html) on implementing callbacks if you want to follow my advice

Now, for the relationship between the manager and the view i do agree that you should use an observer pattern, this will allow you to create different views that react differently to the same events. This means that it's `DataManager` that should extend `Observable`, and every view listening it should implement `Observer`

Finally, i have to say that if you plan on having different types of events, the JDK observable and observer (java.util) mechanism is not very clean. My biggest criticism is that the second argument of update is an `Object`, so you end up with a huge list of if else where you need to check `instanceof` like in your example, which in general is [not good practice](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31). An alternative is to use the event notification mechanism from the UI classes (like `EventObject` and `EventListener`) , they are part of the UI classes but are really more generic than just UIs. see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897928/how-to-use-java-observers-updateobservable-object-function)

Oh and if you can, try to avoid cascading events. It makes code hard to read and debug. Maybe the view could observe directly the HttpHelper??

Comment: I use Observer because I have many DataManager and View instance classes, which listening change from HttpHellper, as updated question.

Comment: In that case I would say it's ok to cascade the event since there are several managers and it seems they are not just propagating the event but actually processing it and creating something new with it which is what gets dispatched to the views. Add some checks to only dispatch the events when the values change. This will 1) minimize the number of calls and 2) break infinite event loops if in the future you create a listeners loop

Comment: Thanks, I choose the relationship between the manager and the view is observer pattern, manger and httphelper I use an delegate (event listener), like your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make the `View` an `Observable` but that chain of Observation may make your code complex.

The immediate solution came to me is:

Make an Observer controller

```
class Controller implements Observer{
  DataManager dm;
  View v;

  void update(...){
      Data d = dm.getData();
      v.loadData(d);
  }
}
```

and make your `Controller` observe `HttpHelper`.